# I was sleepy (in the class)

Tags: usage

I know that normally we use 'J'ai sommeil' to mean 'I am sleepy' or 'I want to go to bed' etc.

But for e.g. if you just attended a class which was really boring and you recount that to a friend, would you say the following sentence?

> J'ai eu sommeil pendant le cours parce que le prof était ennuyant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many possibilities.

> J'ai eu du mal à rester éveillé (parce que le prof était ennuyant).

Seems the best to me. There is the idea that you felt sleepy but you didn't actually sleep.

> J'ai eu sommeil pendant le cours parce que le prof était ennuyant.

Is grammatically correct but is strange as "avoir sommeil" suggest that you are tired more than sleepy.

Comment: merci beaucoup...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can say :

"J'ai eu sommeil pendant le cours parce que le prof était ennuyant"

It's the same than :

"I was sleepy because ..."

Comment: merci. Et pour raconter une chose habituelle- par eg à un médecin si un certain médicament me rendre "sleepy", puis-je dire ' j'ai sommeil quand je prends ce comprimé' ?

Comment: Pour dire que quelque chose te rends "sleepy", tu peux dire : "Ce médicament me donne envie de dormir" ou plus précisément : "Ce médicament me fatigue".

Comment: merci beaucoup ...

Answer (score 0):

*J'ai eu sommeil* is fine but *ennuyant* is no more use in that acception in France (see http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2410 ) :

> j'ai eu sommeil pendant le cours parce que le prof était ennuyeux.

or better, to emphasize the fact the teacher was really boring:

> j'ai eu sommeil pendant le cours tellement le prof était ennuyeux.

If you were really about to sleep (but didn't really), i.e. you dozed off, you might also have said :

> J'ai somnolé pendant le cours tellement le prof (or le cours) était ennuyeux.

Comment: So what does the adjective 'ennuyant' signify if it does not mean 'boring'?

Comment: OOps I didn't notice the link that you provided. Thanks a lot as I learnt a new thing today.

Comment: In modern French of France, *ennuyant* is only a present participle, not an adjective which is *ennuyeux*.